# C# Генерация PDF-отчёта

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

Каким образом лучше автоматизировать генерацию PDF отчётов? Должен быть некоторый шаблон отчёта, который заполняется данными и преобразуется в PDF файл. За шаблон можно взять документ Word, HTML-страницу, даже PDF-файл (что неудобнее всего). Может быть есть ещё какие то варианты, о которых я не знаю? Слышал ещё про XSL-FO, но не понимаю как его здесь можно применить. При этом важно чтобы шаблон можно было красиво оформить - с таблицами, иконками, разными шрифтами и начертаниями (возможно удобнее всего в этом случае HTML шаблон, который заполняется данными по каким-нибудь ключевым словам).

Comment: Я в рабочем проекте брал за шаблон WPF-страницу, вставлял в неё текст (через Binding), и рендерил её в WPF. При этом разбивку на страницы приходилось делать вручную (измеряя текущую глубину наполнения `StackPanel`). Это не самый лёгкий путь, и не позволяет править шаблон после компиляции (что наверное не очень хорошо).

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать такие библиотеки как FastReport.